# De onde vem e o que significa a expressão "fica gel"?

Tags: significado, origem

Já ouvi algumas vezes a expressão "fica gel", mas seu significado nunca ficou claro. Seria algo como "fique tranquilo"? E de onde vem tal expressão? Seria apenas um encurtamento da expressão "fica gelo"?

Achei um exemplo de uso [aqui](http://fikagel.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/bem-vindos-fica-gel-ai-galera.html), mas não foi tão esclarecedor para mim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Já ouvi esta expressão no Rio Grande do Sul e tenho o mesmo entendimento que você. Entendo como "fica frio", "fica tranquilo". O [dicionário informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/fica+gelo/) traz uma resposta para "fica gelo", que entendo ter o mesmo sentido que "fica gel":

> O mesmo que ficar frio, fica de boa.
>
> > Não se preucupa (sic), fica gelo

Quanto à origem, realmente parece um encurtamento, mas não tenho fontes que confirmem essa informação. Espero que tenha lhe ajudado!

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE! Poderias adicionar o link ao dicionario informal que mencionaste? Assim sua resposta ficaria mais completa e outros poderiam conhecer esta referência online para futuras consultas!

Comment: Acho que "fica frio" e "fica de boa" dava outra pergunta ;)

Comment: @JorgeB., quanto à origem, sim, com certeza. Nos últimos anos, a expressão "ficar de boa" começou a ser muito usada, mas, por algum motivo, não gosto dessa expressão!

Comment: "fica frio", "fica gelo", "fica gel", são gírias, regionais no caso de "fica gel" e "fica gelo".

Comment: "Ficar gel" é mais do que "ficar tranquilo", muitas vezes significa "ser discreto" ou "ficar quieto". Digo isso por experiência própria, uma vez que as pessoas do meu círculo social usam essa expressão.

Answer (score 4):

Aparentemente, "Fica gel" tem o sentido de "Fica frio", "Fica tranquilo". Embora a sua origem seja desconhecida, parece ser uma expressão bastante antiga.

Encontrei entre as comunidades do já extinto Orkut um post de Setembro de 2005 sobre a expressão: [Fica Gel! A LEGÍTIMA](http://orkut.google.com/c5021040.html).
Nela temos uma descrição do que seria o tal sentido da expressão:

> Ficar ou não ficar GEL !? 
>   Ficar GEL é um estado de espírito onde você se aproxima de algo superior, algo de outra dimensão. Estar GEL significa despreender-se de problemas e males que atormentam sua cachola. Vale ressaltar que ficar GEL siginifica acima de tudo, FICAR GEL.

Comment: Acrescentei a data do post do Orkut. Numa língua com vários séculos, a expressão «muito antiga» fica um bocado ambígua :)